Can this circuit work?
Here is a radio receiver circuit shown in the diagram. I want to make this circuit on bread board or perf board for the frequency of 800 kHz but I wonder can this circuit be able listen to the required radio frequency?
1: I will choose specific values of inductor and capacitor to tune the filter to resonate at 800 KHz.
2: I will have to match the Impedance of antenna LC circuit and output.
Is this all needed to make this circuit after choosing the proper antenna?
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-circuit-of-a-simple-radio-receiver-9_fig1_317185184


You might care to start from a practical crystal radio tutorial (perhaps this or this and very many others), rather than a unreviewed paper about "DNA teleportation". ( Which says "We are designing a circuit for teleportation with DNA and guess that cancer can be cured via this method."  Though obviously that would be quite nice.)

this is already designed for amplitude modulated signals, as explained in my previous comment.

Do you want to listen to 800 MHz or 800 KHz?  800 KHz is in the normal AM broadcast band - your circuit should work at that frequency, but is unlikely to work at 800 MHz.

Peter so this circuit will work for 800khz? Sorry I wrote 800 mhz by mistake. Kindly give me the answer I detail. I will accept your answer.

What you show is a diagram without any values nor assembly instructions. In this circuit, the real values and construction method will determine the performance. The diode should be a low-power RF Schottky type. The headphones need to be "high" impedance type, say above 10kΩ coil impedance.
Do you have any high power AM broadcast transmitters nearby - say within 100km? If not, this radio may not be sensitive enough to receive much.
If you use a large external dipole antenna, then such a radio will perform acceptably for nearby stations. By "large dipole" I mean at least quarter-wave so 93m long, or a large hexagon or circular coil - say 1-2m in diameter. The coil antennas are directional enough that they should be oriented with their axis pointed toward the transmitter.
It is often forgotten how radio was done in the times when those crystal sets were of any practical use for broadcasts. The receive antennas were long dipoles hanging outside between trees, or human sized circular/hexagonal coils - larger if possible. If you connect an antenna that can fit inside of an apartment/home, expect to receive nothing unless you live in a castle with very long hallways :), or the transmitter is nearby.

Can this circuit work?

Yes. Will it work for you? Doubtful unless you show us how you've assembled it etc.
This receiver hangs the demodulator directly on the so-called antenna coil  (inductor symbol on the schematic). Normally the antenna coil would feed a preamplifier stage or a mixer, with input impedances much higher than that of a headphone set. Here you have a tuned tank that has to provide all the necessary selectivity. With the headphone load it is damped heavily and thus won't be very selective. So you may hear several strong stations overlapping.
This circuit can be improved a lot just by adding a baseband preamplifying stage. It will be way more selective.
For tuning the antenna circuit you can use a 10-20m of wire wound in a square or polygon, connected to a 555-based oscillator. The oscillator should have two settings to make sure you're tuning really to 800kHz. For example, 800kHz and 267kHz. A 555 produces square waves that have odd harmonics. So if your receiver is tuned to 800kHz, you can switch between the 800kHz oscillator and 267kHz oscillator feeding the "transmitter" coil, and the receiver will receive either the fundamental of 800kHz or the 3rd harmonic of 267kHz. 2nd harmonic of 800kHz is 1600kHz, but the 267kHz oscillator has no odd harmonics there. So if you can receive from both oscillators, you'll be quite likely to be listening to 800kHz.

What if I connect an amplifier or a multistage amplifier between lc circuit and the diode connected to speaker? Will it work then?

At that point you may as well build a super-regenerative receiver, or a so-called selective receiver that demodulates the baseband signal that was selectively amplified. The diode cannot drive a speaker no matter if you use an amplifier before it or not. It needs high impedance headphones. So, either way you'll need to experiment and design something. What is your reason for building this - learning? If so, you may want to look for real, tested, popular receiver designs used by hams (radio amateurs) the world over. Several to choose from, and at least you will know they work.

Yes learning. I am trying to make and understand a radio receiver
